# Hook object load event in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

Is there an EF equivalent to LINQ to SQL's OnCreated partial?

Several of my objects have XML fields that I would like to parse whenever the object is loaded from the db - I'd like to put the XML data into more friendly strongly-typed collections. I've already marked the XML field as private and hooked the SavingChanges event to re-build the XML before the item is committed back to the db, but I can't figure out how to populate the collections whenever the object is loaded.

I've thought of using the OnFieldChanged partial for my XML field, but that would run again whenever the XML field is re-built during SavingChanges, so it seems  like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `OnLoaded` event or similar as far as I know. A workaround might be to expose the collections as properties and lazily create/parse the values on first access:

```
private List<SomeData> _parsedDataCache;
public IList<SomeData> ParsedData {
    get {
        if (_parsedDataCache == null)
            ParseData();
        return _parsedDataCache;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done this for a few fields.. I tend to put a generic [Data] NVARCHAR(MAX)  field on all my tables for such extensibility.. then I have a   void SetData(action<XElement data> runner)   method.  This allows the context to translate to a base XElement from the string (cached), then update after... I also wired in via the SavingChanges to call a  private void BeforeSave()  method if it exists in an entity's partial...  works pretty well overall.

Answer (score 3):

Or use ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized event in .net 4.0

Answer (score -2):

You should create a partial class (as you do in LINQ to SQL) and just use the default constructor.

Comment: This doesn't work. The XML field values are not set at construction time yet.

Comment: the initial question was "Is there an EF equivalent to LINQ to SQL's OnCreated partial" - which my answer is relevant to.